# 'Rename-Item' makes a copy with the new name

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

Trying to make a script to backup specific folders and then rename the GUID key for the target user under HKLM...\ProfileLists but the rename-item command makes a copy of the key and creates a new key with the appended name though having full access

Tried with -force, tried with move-item instead of rename but it gives the exact same results, a new identical key as original but with an appended name

```bsh
if ((Test-Path $FULLPATH)) { 
    Rename-Item $FULLPATH -NewName "$SSID.bak" -Force 
    if ($?) { 
         Write-Host "$USERNAME was SUCCESSFULLY renamed in the registry" 
    } 
}
```

Expected result is to only rename the GUID-key in the registry.
Actual result is a duplicate key with the new duplicate to have the correct appended name.

> Rename-Item : The registry key at the specified path does not exist.
>   At line:9 char:5
>   +     Rename-Item $FULLPATH -NewName "$SSID.bak" -Force
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument:   (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...\folderredirect:String) [Rename-Item], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
>
> Rename-Item : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   At line:9 char:5
>   +     Rename-Item $FULLPATH -NewName "$SSID.bak" -Force
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Rename-Item], NullReferenceException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NullReferenceException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand

The key does exist and I can run the same command again as proof (due to the test-path).

Verbose output do confirm its copying

```
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy Key" on target "the key in question"
```

Comment: IMO the small  code fragment/details you provided isn't sufficient to give any hints.

Comment: It may be you need `Rename-ItemProperty` - more (relevant) details help us help you.

Comment: It's always worth striving for an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.  Are your variables set in this way?

```
$SSID = 'S-1-5-21-1212123708-1212126490-1212120831-1001'
$FULLPATH = 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-1212123708-1212126490-1212120831-1001'
rename-item $fullpath -newname "$SSID.bak"
```

Comment: Yes, sort of - 
`$USERNAME = read-host "Enter Username"
$SID = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserAccount -Filter "Name = '$USERNAME'"
$SSID = $SID.SID
$REGPATH = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
$FULLPATH = "$REGPATH\$SSID" `

Comment: @user3415995 The error message suggests otherwise though.. `$REGPATH` should either start with `HKLM:` or `Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (alternative path that begins with the provider name followed by **two** colons)

Comment: You might put all that in the question.  It seems like it should work unless something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to rename the keys with rename-item with full paths and not using variables either. However resolved it by replacing rename-item to

`# Rename the Registry profile 
if ((Test-Path $FULLPATH)) {
      reg copy "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$SSID" "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$SSID-$(Get-Date -f yyy-MM-DD)" /s /f
    if (( $? -eq 'True' )) {
      reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$SSID" /f
    }
    if (( $? -eq 'True' )) {
      Write-Host "$USERNAME was SUCCESSFULLY renamed in the registry"
    }`

had to use half the full path in the reg copy/delete commands as the syntax is different (no colon). This worked